# how to save data from a multiple select in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have this multiple select from a form:

```
    {{Form::select('category[]',$category_details,null,array('multiple'=>true,'class'=>'custom-scroll')); }}
```

i am trying to save the data to db with the fallowing action:

```
    public function store()
{

    foreach(Input::get(category) as $selected_id){
        $new_post=array(
            'categories_id' => $selected_id,
            'title'         => Input::get('title'),
            'body'          => Input::get('body'),
            'user'          => Input::get('user'),
        );
        $post = new Post($new_post);
    $post -> save();

        $last_post_id=$post->id;

        $category_post= new CategoryPost;
        $category_post->category_id=$selected_id;
        $category_post->post_id=$last_post_id;
    $category_post->save();
    }


    return Redirect::to('smart/posts.index');
}
```

but i get the fallowing error:  Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

could you please guide me on how should I process the data in order to be able to save it to db.

one more thing, the form works ok if I change from a multiple select to a classic select item

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the opening form

I had this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('id' => 'post_form', 'class' => 'smart-form' )) }}
```

and it should have been this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'posts','id' => 'post_form', 'class' => 'smart-form' )) }}
```